# Describing $\langle x,y : x^{2} , y^{3} , [x,y] , x^{6}y^{6}\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to identify the following presentation

> $\langle x,y : x^{2} , y^{3} , [x,y] , x^{6}y^{6}\rangle$

I substituted  the first relation in the final one and got $x^{6}=1$ so the group is cyclic of order 6
The problem is why we can't say that the schreier transversal is $\{x^{0}.....x^{5}\}$ so we omit the other generator $y$.

The correct answer in fact is claiming that the transversal is $\{x^{i}y^{j}\}$. But in another case for The presentation of the cyclic group of order 7 we omit the other generator.

Comment: Have you made a mistake in your relations? The first is $x^2$ and the final is $y^6$, how do you substitute one into the other?

Comment: Yes @Robert Chamberlain

Comment: I corrected the mistake thanks alot

Comment: "I substituted the first relation in the final one and got $x^6 =1$". Sure. But this does not imply that the group is cyclic of order 6...($x$ has order 2 so obviously $x^6=1$...I mean, it is also true that $x^{12223534}=1$, but so what?!?)

Answer (score 7):

The relators $x^2$, $y^3$ and $[x, y]$ combine to imply the third relator, $x^6y^6$. So your group is:
$$
\langle x, y; x^2, y^3, [x, y]\rangle
$$
Note that the cross product $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ satisfies this presentation (why?). It then follows that your group is precisely this presentation (why?).

This means that your group is cyclic of order 6 (why? - this is where the transversal being $\{x^iy^j\}$ comes from).

Note that although the group is cyclic of order 6, it is *not for the reasons which you give in your question*. In particular, in your question you imply that $x$ has order 6 as $x^6=1$. However, $x$ has order 2.

Comment: So why in the case of cyclic group of order 7 the transversal is simply the cyclic group of order 6 while the the transversal of the giving prisintation needs booth generators @user1729

Comment: Well, do you know why $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: Yes I know that .my concern is in the transversal @user1729

Comment: So you realise that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ can be generated by the elements $2$ and $3$, so $\mathbb{Z}_6=\langle 2, 3\rangle$, even though neither element has order $6$?

Answer (score 1):

If you examine $$(xy)^0, (xy)^1, (xy)^2, (xy)^3, (xy)^4, (xy)^5, (xy)^6 \dots$$ you reduce to $$1, xy, y^2, x, y, xy^2, 1 \dots$$ and the sequence repeats. It is just that the presentation you are given does not exhibit a generator of the whole group. There are non-trivial elements of the group such as $x, y, y^2$ which are not generators.

As for the cyclic group of order $7$, since $7$ is prime every non-identity element generates the group.

Is this what is causing your confusion?